# reuse and extend PresenterWidget GWTP?

Tags: gwt-platform

i am new to GWT and GWTP and the question sounds stupid.. Can I make an abstract PresenterWidget or similiar? 
Like in normal Java extending the "class" and reuse / extend the logic. But not only the class, the whole thing of View and Presenter. I try to explain my initial situation and maybe you have another idea. [image: example gui]

The image hopefully helps to explain it. The "Main-Tab" and every other tab consists of a collection of views which have the same base structure and the same logic.

the base structure consists of

- border around EVERYTHING
- an image (the wwitch)
- a title
- a textarea
- a PresenterWidget which is added to a contentSlot of the parent (the menu left)

and below the base are view specific components like buttons, text or any other widget. So a main part of the view with logic is repeading. If the switch is "toggled" the view is hidden (the textarea and any childs / view specific components) like the lowest view in the picture. Furthermore the PresenterWidget left changes the color.

The logic is working, but now I am searching a proper way to solve this without repeading code and the possibility to add child elements which are hidden as well by toggling the switch. Can I add to a PresenterWidget child widgets and define where there should be added? like:    Even if this is possible, it feels a bit inconvenient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to post the solution:

I have now a simple Composite (KPICommonView) for the switch, title and the description. It got another FlowPanel below the description, where the specific components will be added later. For this the Composite implements "HasWidgets" and overrides the "add(Widget w)"-method which is called by UiBinder if the Widget is added and has child elements.

```
<own:KPICommonView title="First Header" description="I am a happy description :)" anchorToken="{nameAnchors.getFirst}">
   <g:Label>child component</g:Label>
</own:KPICommonView>
```

I am not sure if I do a PresenterWidget for every segment and every PresenterWidget has one of the KPICommonView added, or if I do one normal Presenter which adds more than one of the CommonViews.
The CommonView furhter creates the PresenterWidget for the menu item on the side. It gets the attributes from the constructor (anchorToken, title) and adds it to the slot (which happens ugly, because the View has hard coded the parent saved to call "addInSlot()". The repeading code for the switch is handled by the KPICommonView.